# Making Tasker write into the external SD card

Tags: external-sd, 5.1-lollipop, tasker, permissions

I'm using Tasker on Android Lollipop (5.1.1). I've come to know that applications now can write to external SD card in Android 5.1.1 update but with the use of an API, for which the user needs to grant permission to the application. I have successfully  done this with ES File explorer.

But, how do I give Tasker the permission to write to external SD Card?

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG: Output]
[image: IMG: Code]

Comment: "Give" might be hard if the app doesn't *request* it. Sure you could do some `pm grant …` – but as you already pointed out, write-access to SD card with LP+ is covered by specific API calls, so an app must use those. If it doesn't, the dev must adjust. Not much a *user* can do about that (at least not without root).

Comment: Okay, I would have thought at least by now, since 36% of Android users are on lollipop that the developer of tasker would have implemented this by now @Izzy

Comment: I'd especially thought so of *Tasker*. Unfortunately, *Tasker* has no decent issue tracker (last time I've checked they still used *Google Groups* which I feel a horror tool for things like that), or I had recommended 1. checking open issues to support and, if none found, 2. open an issue on it. Hm, they still do use GGroups. See here: [Tasker unable to write external SD card on Marshmallow ?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/zuY21R_bvyU)

Comment: I have read that page numerous times, I haven't tried moving the files to the Android folder for tasker, that being becuse it would be only half the job done. And out of the numerous apps on the play store, I thought tasker might have been one of them that had supported the new all. And @Izzy Good luck in the election, I will vote for you

Comment: Thanks Matt! And sorry that I can't help further with this issue (first, I've no device running LP+ currently – and second, IMHO that's something that needs to be fixed by the dev).

Comment: Yea, thought that it a) The devs haven't implemented the solution yet, or b) that something was stuffing up on my end. Thanks for clarifying this for me. EDIT: Do you know where I can put a feature request for tasker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tasker/zuY21R_bvyU
where Pent said:

Here's a nice link explaining the situation:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eyes-free/rspqjlmu_ss

As I understand it, if on lollipop or 'portable' mode on marshmallow are used, access is required via a special API. I've looked at this API (DocumentFile) and it's going to require rewriting huge chunks of code used for the file functions, plus some awkwardness with the user pre-accepting file operations
on external SD (and I don't know how long that preacceptance stays valid, potentially making it
useless for later automation)

Summary, I'm not going to be doing this in the near future, if more mainstream devices start to get SD I may reconsider.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am gonna take a guess that you are the applications developer?? correct?? With the marshmallow update (which i currently can't get, stuck on lollipop) if the user where to select the SD card storage option as Internal instead of portable, this problem then shouldn't occur, correct?, due to the fact that the SD card is treated as internal memory. But with the Samsung galaxy S7 adopting SD cards again other manufacturers may follow suit, but not everyone is gonna want to use the SD card as internal memory, what I am trying to say is phone may start to get SD cards back....

Comment: so you may start to get this problem more and more often from user and it would be very helpful for users to be able to implement SD card operations again. But it is up to the developer to add support

Answer (score 0):

First link above have the solution on Dustin answer. You should use any file manager to create a folder inside `data` like that

`/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm/`

And use Tasker to copy to that folder. You can move it elsewhere later.
A folder like

`/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm/whatever`

will also work. Tested on Android 5.1.1 RedMi Pro no root device.

Comment: Back when this question bwas asked, tasker didn't have the ability to write to SD card, now I believe it can, so my above question is now irrelevant. secondly manually moving files defeats the purpose of my question.